# Cannot work with the same file open with 'open(filename)' twice

Tags: python, file

There is no error but for loop doesn't work.

```
textfile = open(path+'\\z.txt','r')

print(textfile.read())                                      #this works

for a in range(len(textfile.read().split())):               #this doesn't
    print(a)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call [`read()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase.read) on the [file object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object) that is returned by [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), "all bytes until EOF (end of file) are returned".

That means, once you call `read()`, it will read the file until the end and "stay" at the end of the file.

If your file is not too large, it's probably best to store the result of `read()` in a varialbe:

```py
textfile = open(path_to_file, 'r')

file_content = textfile.read()

print(file_content)

for a in range(len(file_content.split())):
    print(a)
```

A more idiomatic approach would be to either use [`readlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines), e.g.:

```py
textfile = open(path_to_file, 'r')

# Returns a list of lines, including the newline character:
file_content = textfile.readlines()

for a in range(len(file_content)):
    print(a)
```

or to directly iterate the file object, e.g.:

```py
textfile = open(path_to_file, 'r')

for num, line in enumerate(textfile):
    print(num)
```

If you wanted to use the same file object to iterate the same file again, you could call [`seek(0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek) on it, e.g.:

```py
textfile = open(path_to_file, 'r')

# Print every line in the file:
for line in textfile:
    print(line)

# Reset stream position to zero:
textfile.seek(0)

# Print every line in the file again and
# remove newline and whitespace characters before printing:
for line in textfile:
    print(line.strip())
```